# Solution to x^x=a

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

I have a possible solution to this problem that doesn't use logarithms or W function and I would like to know if it is OK.

We can rewrite the equation in this way:

\begin{equation} X=a^{1/x} \to x=a^{1/(a^{1/x})}=a^{a^{-1/x}} \to a^{a^{-1/(a^{1/x})}}\to x=a^{a^{-a^{-1/x}}}\end{equation} And applying the same arguments you reach that the unic solution is \begin{equation} a^{a^{-a^{-a^{-a^{...}}}}}\end{equation}

Comment: The first manipulation is wrong.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: I don't understand why is wrong

Comment: It's not clear, to me at least, how you aim to compute with this.  Take $a=2$, say (for which $x\approx 1.55961$).  Just look at the top part of your iterated exponent we see that $z=(-2)^z$, right?  But that has no real solutions.  How did you intend to proceed?

Comment: But the - 2 isn't between parenthesis because the exponent doesn't affect to the minus. And this has real solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is correct and indeed powerful.

Solving for $x$ using the Lambert $W$ function, we get $x = \frac{\ln(a)}{W(\ln(a))}$.

Equating the two expressions, you get the following marvellous representation of the Lambert $W$ function which is valid for $e^{-1/e} \leq x \leq e^e$:

$$x^{{{{x}^{-x}}^{-x}}^{...}} = x^{{{{(1/x)}^{(1/x)}}^{(1/x)}}^{...}} = \frac{\ln(x)}{W(\ln(x))}$$

In fact, a similar result was shown by Euler $(1783)$ and Eisenstein $(1844)$, that is

$$f(z) = z^{z^{z^{z^{z^{...}}}}} = \frac{-W(-\ln(z))}{\ln(z)}, \, e^{-e} \leq z \leq e^{1/e}$$

Knoebel $(1981)$ also demonstrated that
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^n\ln^n(z)}{(n+1)!} = 1 + \ln(z) + \frac{3^2(\ln(z))^2}{3!} + ...$$

I hope you take pride in your discovery for that someone discovered a result before you is merely an accident of time.

Reference: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html